# String compare Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, compare

I've been struggling with a simple comparison but I can't get it to work.
I´m reading a XML file and I need to compare data from it in order to show the right picture.

http://www.cleaner.se/larm.xml  (Example file for parsing)

I have tried things like:

```
if([aLarm.larmClass isEqualToString:@"A"])
    NSLog(@"same");
 else
    NSLog(@"Not same");
```

If I use: `NSLog(aLarm.larmClass);`  console puts it out nicely as it should. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what IS "aLarm.larmClass"? is it a string? need more info.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the NSString compare: methods. For example:

```
if ([myString caseInsensitiveCompare:@"A"] == NSOrderedSame ) {
    NSLog(@"The same");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not the same.");
}
```

The result is an NSComparisonResult which is just an enum with types NSOrderedSame, NSOrderedAscending and NSOrderedDescending.

Check the documentation on the various compare: methods [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-caseInsensitiveCompare_).

Of course, if the receiver is actually an NSString, then isEqualToString: should also work. So if you're trying to compare a class name (aLarm.larmClass ??), then you can call:

```
if ([NSStringFromClass([aLarm class]) isEqualToString:@"A"] ) {
    NSLog(@"The same");
}
```

Comment: I think my name larmClass if confusing, its a NSString and not a class. So i reach it with calling the objekt from my class "aLarm" ie: aLarm.larmClass as well as aLarm.description

Answer (score 0):

If the `larmClass` property is a string, make sure that it is actually one character in length (i.e. it doesn't have any leading or trailing whitespace that was accidentally included when parsing the XML). If the `larmClass` property truly is an `NSString` containing the letter ‘A’ then `[aLarm.larmClass isEqualToString:@"A"]` will return `YES`.

Do a:

```
NSLog(@"%u, %@", [aLarm.larmClass length], aLarm.larmClass);
```

and just make sure that it shows “`1, A`”.

Comment: I guess you where right m8. I had a \n in front of it that I removed and then It worked. tnx for feedback and great Ideas to make me solve it. reg: Mandel