# Compare the text of two text fields

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, string-comparison

How do you compare the text in two text fields to see if they are the same, such as in "Password" and "Confirm Password" text fields?

```
if (passwordField == passwordConfirmField) {

    //they are equal to each other

} else {

    //they are not equal to each other

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071221/string-compare-objective-c also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592511/string-comparison-in-objective-c

Comment: No, kind of close, but not exactly. I want to compare the text in TWO text fields to one another, not one text field to a specific string.

Comment: You know how to get the string out of one text field, right? So you get the second one the same way, and then you have two strings that you compare like any others.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Objective-C you should use [`isEqualToString:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407803-isequaltostring), like so:

```
if ([passwordField.text isEqualToString:passwordConfirmField.text]) {
    //they are equal to each other
} else {
    //they are *not* equal to each other
}
```

`NSString` is a pointer type. When you use `==` you are actually comparing two memory addresses, not two values. The `text` properties of your fields are 2 different objects, with different addresses.
So `==` will always<sup>1</sup> return `false`.

---

In Swift things are a bit different. The Swift `String` type conforms to the [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) protocol. Meaning it provides you with equality by implementing the operator `==`. Making the following code safe to use:

```
let string1: String = "text"
let string2: String = "text"

if string1 == string2 {
    print("equal")
}
```

And what if `string2` was declared as an `NSString`?

```
let string2: NSString = "text"
```

The use of `==` remains safe, thanks to some bridging done between `String` and `NSString` in Swift.

---

1: Funnily, if two `NSString` object have the same value, the compiler **may** do some optimization under the hood and re-use the same object. So it is **possible** that `==` **could** return `true` in some cases. Obviously this not something you want to rely upon.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by using the isEqualToString: method of NSString like so:

```
NSString *password = passwordField.text;
NSString *confirmPassword = passwordConfirmField.text;

if([password isEqualToString: confirmPassword]) {
    // password correctly repeated
} else {
    // nope, passwords don't match
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will actually check if the two memory addresses are equal, not the contents of the string... so it will always end up in the ELSE

Comment: Are you sure ? From what I understand from the doc, isEqual: will compare the hash of to object. If you use it to compare 2 string objects, it will work. But knowing the two objects are strings, it's faster to use isEqualToString:

Comment: Nope, that's not true. isEqual won't compare memory addresses. It is implemented by the corresponding object it is sent to. In the case of NSString it does compare the contents of both strings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292862/nsstring-isequal-vs-isequaltostring.

Comment: True, isEqualToString is faster. You should prefer using that.

Comment: I stand corrected! I just always associate isEqual: with comparing objects, not their contents...