# Checking if password field and verify password fields are not equal?

Tags: iphone, xcode, passwords, registration, verify

I have a registration form on an app im working on. You enter your email then your desired password and a verify password. It needs to check if the two password fields`passwordFieldOne` and `passwordFieldTwo` and not equal. They need to check if they are not equal for my error process to work correctly. Here are some things I tried.

```
    if(passwordFieldOne != passwordFieldTwo){
        //do whatever
    }
```

-

```
    if(passwordFieldOne.text != passwordFieldTwo.text){
        //do whatever
    }
```

-

```
    if((passwordFieldOne.text == passwordFieldTwo.text) == False){
        //do whatever
    }
```

PS. Please dont respond telling me I can just check if they are equal, or check if they are equal and then say else. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905751/compare-the-text-of-two-text-fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-(BOOL)isPasswordMatch:(NSString *)pwd withConfirmPwd:(NSString *)cnfPwd {
//asume pwd and cnfPwd has not whitespace
    if([pwd length]>0 && [cnfPwd length]>0){
        if([pwd isEqualToString:cnfPwd]){
           NSLog(@"Hurray! Password matches ");
           return TRUE;
        }else{
           NSLog(@"Oops! Password does not matches");
           return FALSE;
        }
    }else{
         NSLog(@"Password field can not be empty ");
         return FALSE;
    }
return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Just little improve of code, you are not checking the 'space' count.. do you?

Comment: @Sterling Lutes No problem :)

Answer (score 5):

Use  `isEqualToString:` method for comparing strings:

```
if([passwordFieldOne.text isEqualToString:passwordFieldTwo.text]) {
    // passwords are equal
}
```

Comment: And, naturally, if you want to check for inequality, just put a not (`!`) operator in front of the statement: `if(![passwordFieldOne.text isEqualToString:passwordFieldTwo.text])`

Comment: Thanks but I want to compare if they are unequal.

Comment: Add ! operator between ( and [

Answer (score 0):

You below code of comparing _passwordText and _confirmPasswordText

```
  if ([_passwordText.text isEqual:_confirmPasswordText.text])
        {
            NSLog(@"Password =%@   , ConfirmPassword = %@ is equal ",_passwordText.text,_confirmPasswordText.text);
        }
        else {
            UIAlertController *alertConnection= [UIAlertController
                                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@""
                                                 message:@"Password do not match! "
                                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
            UIAlertAction* okBtnConnection= [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
                                                                       [self.view endEditing:YES];
                                                                   }
                                             ];
            [alertConnection addAction:okBtnConnection];
            [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIAlertController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            [self presentViewController:alertConnection animated:YES completion:nil];
```